# Execute a procedure on a shared server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, odbc

I have a SQL Server that connects to an Oracle db via ODBC.

On the sql box I am trying to call a test procedure with:

```
EXEC ('CALL [WORKSPACE_NAME].[PKG_TEST.N_test]') AT [SHARED_SERVER];
```

I get the following:

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00936: missing expression

It is a simple package that requires no parameters, to confirm the process is working it is a simple update:

```
procedure N_test 
as
begin
N_AUDIT.AUDIT_ITEM(1, 'Start');
    update N_audits
    set 
        AUDIT_IMAGE_ATTACHED = 'Y'
    where audit_id = 14; 
N_AUDIT.AUDIT_ITEM(2, 'Update complete');
commit;

end N_test;
```

If i run this in Oracle it updates the table as required.

I am not sure if Im doing the SQL call correctly. I can pull info using:

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM WORKSPACE.TABLE') AT [SHARED_SERVER];
```

With this I assume the connetion is ok and its an issue calling the procedure.

I am new to this and can't see where I an going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call just a *package*; you need to call its *procedure* or a *function*.

Comment: @ Littlefoot I tried to simplify the string above,  I actually call PKG_TEST.update_table with the update_table being the function

Comment: It is difficult to debug code you can't see. Any chance for you to edit the question and provide some additional info, such as procedure name you call (along with its parameters)? Does the procedure correctly work when ran directly in Oracle database? Don't *oversimplify* information because it is misleading. For example, `SELECT TABLE' would raise the same ORA-00936. More accurate info we have, sooner you'll get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have updated with additional info.